# Moshi: Platform class java.lang.Class requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm using a Moshi adapter to get the object from a JSON string. But, I'm getting an error,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.lang.Class requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

All the data members of the UserProfile class are only String type then why it is asking to create an explicit JsonAdapter?

**MoshiDataConverter**

```
    class MoshiDataConverter() {

    fun <T> getObjectFromJson(typeOfObject: Class<T>, jsonString: String): T? {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter<T>(
                typeOfObject::class.java
        )
        return jsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonString)!!
    }
}
```

**getObject method**

```
fun <T> getObject(@Keys key: String?, typeOfObject: Class<T>?): T? {
    val value = getString(key, null) ?: return null
    return MoshiDataConverter().getObjectFromJson(typeOfObject!!, value)
}
```

**UserProfile.kt**

```
 @Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class UserProfile(
    @get:Json(name = "p_contact")
    val pContact: String? = null,

    @get:Json(name = "profile_pic")
    var profilePic: String? = null,

    @get:Json(name = "lname")
    val lname: String? = null,

    @get:Json(name = "token")
    var token: String? = null,

    @get:Json(name = "fname")
    val fname: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("_id")
    @get:Json(name = "_id")
    var id: String? = null,

    @get:Json(name = "email")
    var email: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    @get:Json(name = "refresh_token")
    var refreshToken: String? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `typeOfObject` parameter is already a class reference, so you don't need to call `::class.java` on it before passing it to the Moshi adapter.

Try replacing

```
val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter<T>(
                typeOfObject::class.java
        )
```

with

```
val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter<T>(typeOfObject)
```